# \member location

Tags: align, positioning, thesis

I have been trying to finish my thesis and have a few errors that I could not have solved yet. I want to align my committee members' names to the left side. How can I do it? This is how it looks like. Thank you.

```
\firstmember{Thomas Muller, Advisor}
\secondmember{c. Ronalo}
\thirdmember{Lionel Messi}[Department of Mechatronics Engineering][X University]
```

[image]

Comment: presumably you have  file that defines `\firstmember` but unless you say what that is it's impossible even to guess an answer.

Comment: There's no way to know how those commands are defined a priori. We need to see the full code of the page, including the document class and whatever is in the preamble necessary for the signature page.